# have to remove unicode NEL from textfile in NIFI dataflow

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to remove the unicode char NEL from my flowfiles in NIFI dataflow 
Until now i have used replacetext processor to cleanse data, but how do i search for a unicode string from within replacetext processor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1/ I just copy-paste that [symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/browsertest.htm)  into search string.

2/ use expression: `${literal('&#133;'):unescapeXml()}`

3/ you can replace char with script (groovy)

```java
def ff = session.get()
if(!ff)return
ff = session.write(ff, {rawIn, rawOut->
    rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){reader->
        rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
            reader.transformChar(writer){ch-> ch==(char)'\u0085' ? '' : ch }
        }
    }
} as StreamCallback)
session.transfer(ff, REL_SUCCESS)
```